# How to get childrens of sqlalchemy gino aiogram 3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, telegram-bot, aiogram, gino

I have a User relationship with an Order. I can get `order.user` via the connection and everything works fine here, but when I try to get all the user’s orders `user.orders`, I only get an error.

file **user.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database.app import db

STATUS_UNREGISTER = 'unregister'
STATUS_REGISTER = 'register'
STATUS_DECLINED = 'declined'
STATUS_LOGOUT = 'logout'
STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active'
STATUS_BANNED = 'banned'

ROLE_USER = 'user'
ROLE_ADMIN = 'admin'


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    telegram_id = Column(BigInteger)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    username = Column(String)
    role = Column(String)
    status = Column(String)
    pubg_id = Column(BigInteger)
    login = Column(Integer)
    password = Column(String)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)

    # userStats = relationship('UserStats', back_populates='user', uselist=False)
    orders = relationship('Order', back_populates='user')

    _name_idx = db.Index('telegram_id', 'status')
```

file **orders.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, DateTime, String, BigInteger, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database.app import db


STATUS_CREATE = 'create'
STATUS_COMPLETED = 'completed'
STATUS_DECLINED = 'decline'


class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(String)
    uc = Column(String)
    sum = Column(Float)
    pubg_id = Column(BigInteger)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)
    paid_at = Column(DateTime)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    user = relationship('User', back_populates='orders')
```

file **db.py**

```
async def get_active_users():
    return await User.load(orders=Order).query.where((User.status == 'active') | (User.status == 'logout')).gino.all()
```

the file where I'm trying to pull the relationship
file user_stats.py

```
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message

from app.filters.isAdmin import IsAdmin
from database.commands import db

router = Router()
flags = {"throttling_key": "default"}


@router.message(IsAdmin(), F.text.startswith("User Stats "), flags=flags)
async def user_stats(message: Message):
    users = await db.get_active_users()
    for user in users:
        orders = user.orders
        print(orders) # -> thi is error
        for order in orders:
            print(f"User ID: {user.id}, Order ID: {order.id}, Order Status: {order.status}")
```

here is the **error**

```
<database.migrations.orders.Order object at 0x000001EE44A17B00>
Cause exception while process update id=516849479 by bot id=6926508119                                                                          
AttributeError: parent                                                                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                              
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)                                                                                    
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                    
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update    
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(                                                                                         
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                         
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__ 
    return await handler(event, data)                                                                                                           
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                           
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 27, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 41, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 116, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 111, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 144, in _propagate_event
    response = await router.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 116, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 111, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 136, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\PyCharm 2023.3.2\PyProjects\Bogdan_UC_BOT\app\middleware\throttling.py", line 29, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\PyCharm 2023.3.2\PyProjects\Bogdan_UC_BOT\app\http\admin\commands\user_stats.py", line 16, in user_stats
    print(orders)
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 1816, in __str__
    return str(self.parent.class_.__name__) + "." + self.key
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 987, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ivank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 961, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: parent
```